# Find minimum radius of an asteroid before it becomes round using bulk modulus and hydrostatic equilibrium

Tags: newtonian-gravity, pressure, estimation, planets, equilibrium

How big must an asteroid be before gravity makes it round and hydrostatic equilibrium comes into the equation? Let's say that being a round planet requires a radius error of $\frac{\delta R}{R}$ that is less than 0.01. In terms of bulk modulus ($K$), density ($\rho$), and $\frac{\delta R}{R} 
 (r)$, how would I be able to derive the minimum radius ($r_m$) of this asteroid? In other words, I want to figure out how small the asteroid can get to with self-gravity and bulk modulus until it becomes round enough for hydrostatic equilibrium and effects of pressure to come into the equation before it collapses on itself from gravity.

I'm not really sure how to approach a deriving a formula like this. At first, I was thinking of using pressure ($P$) from the bulk modulus equation with $P=\rho g h$, replace $h$ with the minimum radius variable and define the minimum radius by rearranging the formula. But this attempt fails to include the radius error variable into the equation.

Comment: You can't obtain an estimate without a hardness/strength value (or a maximum angle of repose for granular media). You have only a stiffness value—the bulk modulus. You need some type of flow stress or strain; otherwise, all you can say is that gravity will lead to strain energy that may or may not cause rearrangement.

Comment: I think this situation isn't asking us to know what the maximum angle of repose for granular media is. I think the problem wants us to understand how small the asteroid will get to with a bulk modulus of about 2 MBar and self-gravity until hydrostatic equilibrium and pressure prevents it from collapsing from the effects of gravity.

Comment: Again, you need more information. Specifically, some measure of strength. See [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1004/1004.1091.pdf), for example: *" the [so-called] potato radius depends
on the density $\rho$ and the yield strength $\sigma_y$ of the material."*